# holomorphic, bounded function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic for |z| <= R, let $f(0) = 0$, and let $|f(z)| <= M$ for $|z| = R$.
Prove that
$|f(z)|<(M/R)|z|$ for $0<|z|<R$, unless $f(z) = cz$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Heard of the Schwarz lemma?

Comment: yeah...this tells me |f(z)| <= |z| and that f(z) = cz if I have f(z) = |z| for some z.

Comment: Okay. Can you see how to use that here?

Comment: Well, M/R <= 1 --> M <= R...?

Comment: You don't know anything about the relative sizes of $M$ and $R$. Can you from $f$ construct a map to which you can directly apply Schwarz' lemma?

Comment: I cannot :/...I thought f was the function I wanted to use Schwartz on.

Comment: Not directly, you need a function $\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ for Schwarz, that would be the case $R=M=1$. Does that give you an idea?

Comment: Kind of...you mean like g(z) = f(z)/M or something?

Comment: Very close. That takes care of the $M$, now, how could we deal with $R$?

Comment: g(z) = Rf(z)/M ?....by the way thanks for this help.

Comment: No, not that. You have a function defined on $\{z : \lvert z\rvert < R\}$, and you want one defined on $\{z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$.

Comment: So....f(z/R)/M?

Comment: Almost. That would give you a function defined on $\{z : \lvert z\rvert < R^2\}$.

Comment: Ok, so maybe g(z) = f(Rz)/M. This would make g(z) defined on |z| < 1 since |Rz| < R in that case. Then I just use the proof of the Schwarz lemma on g to get the desired result?

Comment: Well, you use the statement of the Schwarz lemma. So $g\colon \mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic with $g(0) = 0$. Schwarz says: ...

Comment: Thank you so much I do believe I can take it from there. You should post an answer so I can vote you up...give me a minute to finish first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bounded holomorphic function $f$ on a disk with $f(0) = 0$, that suggests the Schwarz lemma.

We need to slightly adapt $f$ to obtain a function we can directly apply the lemma to. We need to scale the result to lie in the unit disk, and the argument so that the unit disk is mapped to the domain of $f$, here we look at

$$g(z) = \frac{f(Rz)}{M}.$$

The premises translate into $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1$, and $g(0) = 0$. By the maximum principle, it follows that $g(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$. Now, the Schwarz lemma says that $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert z\rvert$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$, and if there is equality for any $z \in \mathbb{D}\setminus 0$, then $g(z) = c\cdot z$ with $\lvert c\rvert = 1$. The assertions about $f$ follow.